# Symfony 2 ESI Cache

Tags: php, symfony, caching, esi

I have an action which is called in all my page (for logged people only), this action retrieves recent tweets from my twitter account.

API access is limited so I would like the result of this action to be in cache for 10 minutes

```
public function socialAction(){

   $consumerKey = $this->container->getParameter('consumer_key');
   $consumerSecret = $this->container->getParameter('consumer_secret');
   $accessToken = $this->container->getParameter('access_token');
   $accessTokenSecret = $this->container->getParameter('access_token_secret');

   // on appel l'API
   $tweet = new TwitterOAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $accessToken, $accessTokenSecret);
   $screen_name = "blabla";
   $tweets = $tweet->get('statuses/user_timeline', [
       'screen_name' => $screen_name,
       'exclude_replies' => true,
       'count' => 50
   ]);
   $tweets = array_splice($tweets, 0, 5);

   $response = $this->render('GestionJeuBundle:Default:social.html.twig', array("tweets" => $tweets));

   $response->setPublic();
   $response->setSharedMaxAge(600);

   return $response;
```

}

To enable caching I have made ​​the following changes

```
app/config/config.yml

framework:
    esi: { enabled: true }
    fragments: { path: /_proxy }
```

and

```
app/AppCache.php


<?php

require_once __DIR__.'/AppKernel.php';

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\HttpCache\HttpCache;

class AppCache extends HttpCache
{
    protected function getOptions()
    {
        return array(
            'debug'                  => false,
            'default_ttl'            => 0,
            'private_headers'        => array('Authorization', 'Cookie'),
            'allow_reload'           => false,
            'allow_revalidate'       => false,
            'stale_while_revalidate' => 2,
            'stale_if_error'         => 60,
        );
    }
}
```

and

```
web/app_dev.php

<?php

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Debug\Debug;

// If you don't want to setup permissions the proper way, just uncomment the following PHP line
// read http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/installation.html#configuration-and-setup for more information
//umask(0000);

// This check prevents access to debug front controllers that are deployed by accident to production servers.
// Feel free to remove this, extend it, or make something more sophisticated.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', '.....', 'fe80::1', '::1'))
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';
Debug::enable();

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppCache.php';

$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);
$kernel->loadClassCache();
$kernel = new AppCache($kernel);

// When using the HttpCache, you need to call the method in your front controller instead of relying on the configuration parameter
Request::enableHttpMethodParameterOverride();
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
error_log($kernel->getLog());
```

Despite that the page is updated every page refresh (after testing, it does exactly the same things in production environment with change on app.php too)

Have I misunderstood or forgotten a thing ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT solve : i was rendering this action with

```
{{render(controller("GestionJeuBundle:Default:social")) }}
```

changing it for

```
{{render_esi(controller("GestionJeuBundle:Default:social")) }}
```

solve my problem

Hexune

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i was rendering this action with

```
{{render(controller("GestionJeuBundle:Default:social")) }}
```

changing it for

```
{{render_esi(controller("GestionJeuBundle:Default:social")) }}
```

solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

As far as I experimented last weeks, it's worth noting that if you use debug environment in Symfony, Varnish *always* passes-by your request to the back-end.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer, but unfortunately it does exactly the same things in production environment

Comment: What headers your back-end returns to the proxy?

Comment: My header seems to have the good value. The Response header of my action have this : (cache-control =>  public, s-maxage=600, x-debug-token    => 1df192) I'm not sure if the request headers must have something about the cache.

Comment: PS. Don't forget that sending by client/back-end a cookie completely disables caching unless additional configuration is specified.

Comment: sorry didn't know what is VCL (Varnish Configuration Language after search) but i don't know how to find it. My request header of the same action have a Cookies part with ( PHPSESSID, REMEMBERME, _ga, _gat) and cookie param in the request header, it can come from this ?

Comment: i was rendering this action with

{{render(controller("GestionJeuBundle:Default:social")) }}
changing it for

{{render_esi(controller("GestionJeuBundle:Default:social")) }}
solve my problem thanks a lot eRIZ for your time and help, i have learn things i'm not familiar with.